# How much Fragmentation can be optimized before breaking the application

Tags: android, android-fragments, optimization

Recently on the app I have started working, I thought to go full OOP and try out Fragments to make the UI most flexible and reusable as possible.

At least that was the plan.

Here is where I encountered some issues.

I have a BottomNavigationView in my app that has four tabs. Therefore, 4 different fragments.

- HomeFragment
- InboxFragment
- FavoritesFragment
- ProfileFragment

I believe, if I'm using bottomNavigationView, this much fragmentation is unavoidable.

Then when I started to fill out the HomeFragment with content, I find that the file is getting too complicated and huge to easily examine specific parts. This is where I get the idea to create fragments of features that may get used in other activities/views.

So, one such individual fragment is AdvertisementFragment.

Here's where things get interesting. AdvertisementFragment uses code that employs Timer.schedule/Thread.sleep; something to delay a certain function called update.

But the code wasn't being delayed, it sped up instead. Checking the Logcat showed messages like

`Frame time is 8.006377 ms in the future!  Check that graphics HAL is generating vsync timestamps using the correct timebase.`

OR

`Skipped 2 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

I only create the dummy apps for my employer, i.e. If you will, say a "*working*" demo. I'm just a UI designer for them.

Now when I saw these messages popup in my logcat, my first thought was to experiment, how much my device can take before the app crashes. I frantically click away on the four tabs of my bottomNavigationView and sure enough I see the first problem.

Nothing is being loaded in the fragments, its just a white background. All the components, Fragment or Not, weren't showing up, in *any* of the fragments. Then after a few more seconds it crashed. I test the same on two physical devices, and sure enough, it was not the emulator that crashed, my code was the problem.
Even though, it is not my job for optimizing the code, it is going to be a real pain for the developers/users of the app, for the mess that will emerge out of my faulty working model. Hell, if the developers had to redo that, it's going to be more costly.

Which is why, I'm here, is using Fragments within Fragments a good idea? I know about saving Fragment states, but can severely *Fragmented* code be a nuisance to the memory and optimization? If you are talking about saving states of every fragment then would it not consume more memory?

Say, I have a HomeFragment, InboxFragment, etc, from above,  which I load into MainActivity. I can switch between these parent fragments with a bottomNavigationView. Say, HomeFragment itself has 3-5 fragments and rest of the code in HomeFragments is specific to HomeFragment. In other words, let's assume that 40% of code in HomeFragment is Fragments, and the 60% is code specific to HomeFragment. How does that impact performance? What if other parent fragments (InboxFragment, ProfileFragment, etc) have similar constitution of Fragments and Activity specific code?

Can this much Fragmentation be easily/somehow optimized? Or is it outright bad practice?

Comment: Use nested fragments if it makes sense if that particular thing is reusable. Otherwise dump all UI in one fragment. Also, don't make your fragment a god class. Extract business, networking, etc logic into separate classes (viewmodel, repository, usecase, etc)

Comment: It's most likely an issue with the implementation of the fragments and not with the number. Fragments are there to be used and highly optimized and anything else might be more problematic. `Timer.schedule` might leak your frament. `Thread.sleep` might block your UI thread. It might be a good idea, to do some pair-programming with one of your developers and fix the problems you've got. They might know more about it. Have you had a look at some of the demos provided by _Google_?

Comment: First thins are you creating and adding new fragments every time or do you check if fragment exists using findFragmentByTag and show it. This'll probably fix the issue of screen going blank. Second you can use Android profiler to see if memory isn't being freed. You can also use LeakCanary for memory leak as i believe app is crashing after some time due to consumption of all available memory.

Comment: Try to move the business logic to other classes. The fragment is only used for the UI and the life cycle. Do never use Thread.sleep or Timer.schedule. The android Os decides what runs when and how long. It is also  able to kill your app and restore the state of your app.

Comment: Thank you all for you ever so kind comments. I'll take this up for discussion with my developers and work this out. Cheers to @tynn